# Django Admin action different names then function names

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-admin-actions

Is possible to have action display in Django Admin with a different name than its function name?

for example:

```py
 def an_action():
   pass

class AdminPanel(admin.ModelAdmin):
   actions = [ an_action]
```

In the Django admin panel `an_action` would display as "An action". Could I made this display something arbitrary like "Best Action Ever" instead of "An Action"?

Comment: Try: ```an_action.short_description = 'my label' ```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#writing-action-functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```py
def an_action():
   pass
an_action.short_description = 'my label'

class AdminPanel(admin.ModelAdmin):
   actions = [an_action]
```